# How do I get my Ubuntu laptop's display on the ubuntu desktop connected to the network?

Tags: 12.04, networking, remote

My network consists of an ubuntu laptop and an ubuntu desktop connected via a router. Now, I want to work on my laptop and see the output on the desktop screen, through the network. How do I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use Ubuntu's built in utility called Remote desktop or Share your desktop (settings). Its easy and user friendly.